# Azure Data Factory Release Pipeline - Resource Not Found Error

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am testing a build/release of a very simple ADF (just one activity), the build, repository, arm template export all seem ok until when I run the release task, the error shows up in the final step, that says:

```
 "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/htTestDF' under resource group 'xxx-rg' was not found."
  }
```

I watched several tutorials and microsoft web sites, and tried exporting the ARM template several times, the same error occurs. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: share the template, please

Comment: This means the factory you are using does not exist under resource group 'xxx-rg' now. Have you check it before you release this template?You'd better share your template and the screenshots about the ADF.

Comment: Hi I will upload the template shortly. Perhaps I am not understanding the concept. I am getting the same error consistently either doing export/import Template for Data Factory or testing the Azure DevOps Release Pipeline. I have a data factory in a source environment, it is with a different resource group than the tartget env. When I import into the target env, I substitute the resource group parm to the target resource group. It fails. Am I simulating it incorrectly?

Comment: Here is my arm_template.json: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VutmtCJ1xMe5w-o5J9_8l9T4oBXrZxwu?usp=sharing

Comment: When importing the template on the target environment side, I used  "Deploy Custom Template", and loaded this template file. The wizard lets me specify the target environment resource group. After that, when I accept the wizard, the processing will error out with: `{ "error": { "code": "ResourceNotFound", "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/HTDF3' under resource group 'slalom_rg' was not found." }`

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I am not sure if i have to mention your name in order to have this post replied to you so I am mentioning here :)

Comment: @4c74356b41 I am not sure if i have to mention your name in order to have this post replied to you so I am mentioning here :)

Comment: @HT1, I have got it:-) would help you check it.

Comment: @HT1, so in your release task, you replace the resource group as another one? which different from the one used in ADF? I了addition, " I am getting the same error consistently either doing export/import Template for Data Factory" what does mean? According to the template, this was export successfully. isn't it true?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT: yes I replace the resource group because the target environment's resource group name is different than my source environment. 2ndly, I mean I can reproduce this error even doing an import of the ARM template which I have exported from the source environment. Yes, the export was successful. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Upd: I think I know the problem: The ARM Export Template inside the Data Factory IDE exports the details (resources) of the data factory correctly. On the target environment, by importing this template alone is not sufficient. I need to make another template that is specifically for creating a shell data factory resource. I did this by creating another template using "Automation Options" under Creating New Data Factory (for here, I'll call that AutoOptTpl). Once I imported that AutoOptTpl in my target env, then importing my personal data factory template is successful! Is this crazy??

Comment: @HT1, sound crazy, but very reasonable. Please see my explaination. If still has puzzle, feel free to leave comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your details clarifies in comments. Now, the error message you met caused by using a different target resource group as this ARM template deploy to.

To make this more clear, I reproduce the issue based on the details you provided. Fortunately, got the same error with you. Now, let's focus on its log, then get why it cause the `Not Found` error.(Please set **`debug=true`**)

[image]

As I mentioned in the above pic, it is the api that this task used at first step while the template begin to apply into the corresponding resource group and deployment. For more cleared, please refer to this REST API doc firstly: [Deployments - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/createorupdate).

The logic of this task is compile parameters from ARM template file, pack them and use it as request body for this **PUT** api call. See its api doc, you can get that for this API call, its `resourceGroupName` and `deploymentName` need to be specified firstly. In another words, if you specified another target resource group, it would not find the correct target place that can apply this template definition. Because, you can see that this ARM template is preparing to applying activities `SetVariable` into your Data Factory `HTDF3` and the defined `pipelines` name is `HTPipe1`. But these should all not exists in your target Resource Group. Thus it caused the error like this:

```
"error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/Merlin-1003' under resource group 'Merlin-ARM-deploy' was not found."
  }
```

In my sample, `Merlin-ARM-deploy` is my target resource group.

If you want to deploy this into your target resource group, you need to create one data factory manually, or use another ARM Template to create a new one same factory in the target resource group. If you choose the previous method, just then modify the template.json file, to let its parameters correspond to the actual target resource group. But if use the second method, do not operate anything. Just apply them with task.

Comment: thank you for the above. That explains very clearly. Couple of comments: 1) How do I set "debug = true" if I wish to debug? 2) I am surprised that noone seems to have this issue? Surely this has to be pretty standard when doing migration to higher environment (the data factory does not yet exist) - I have watched several youtube videos and blogs and noone has mentioned this. Now I have to package all this to work in the Azure DevOps CICD pipeline, I wonder if you may have a sample release pipeline that solved the above? Thanks again, I will post update if my CICD works

Comment: @HT1 (1) Please go variable tab, then add variable “System.debug” and its value “true”. This can get detailed log of pipeline. (2) As normal, the most often used to deployed the ARM template is database, web app and etc. (Not joking, this is my first try to deploy ADF template) For database or web app, it do not have this limit. Because these template are very general. See this [source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates). What you tried is generated from one specific azure service, it has strong concreteness and low generality.

Comment: @HT1 If you want to apply this template type to another different environment, some parameters must be changed firstly. In addition, for the sample you want, could you express more details? Or you can raise one new ticket and share your demands there. I will according your demands write a sample for you. Also, it can let other SO users or our engineers to help you together:-)

Comment: I tried creating a blank template (just ADF) and then tried to run the template mentioned above. it still won't work. This seems to be an error in ADF git integration

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT "or use another ARM Template to create a new one" this still does not work. What is the proof that this answer worked?

Comment: @BlueClouds, could your express more details on the error you mentioned? If comment has limitation on your words, you can raise new ticket here. Then I could check that clearly.

Comment: Yes I will create a new ticket today. I want to try powershell creation first(blank one) then run the template to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The ARM template generated by ADF(publish) cannot be deployed directly to a new RG.

**Solution**

1. Create RG(optional, assuming it is IAC(infra as code))
2. Run a powershell script task in pipeline to create an empty ADF(do not use empty ARM instead). Since it is not ARM you would need to put an optional condition to check if it already exists)

   Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "RG" -Name "ADF" -Location "North Europe"
3. Now we can execute the ARM template from publish folder (the one [you had given](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VutmtCJ1xMe5w-o5J9_8l9T4oBXrZxwu?usp=sharing))

**Errors in ADF publish system.**

1. The ARM template need to be generated in such a way that it is
   idempotent(should also create afresh if not present). But it is not
   at the moment. It expects an ADF to be present already(strangely).
2. When an empty ARM template created in another RG is used to create a fresh empty ADF in this RG(newly created), it fails. Well, it creates empty ADF but we cannot put adf_publish(default publish folder for ADF) on top of it because we get 'resource not found error'.
3. But when we manually create an ADF and run the adf_publish template
    then it works! But ofcourse, this is not what we want.
4. Why does manual & powershell work(empty + publish) but not ARM template? It could be that the ARM Template has wrong location/region mentioned in it but that was not the case.(really puzzling to me)