# ARM template - Bad JSON content found in the request. (Code:BadRequest)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy a KeyVault in Azure via PowerShell's Az Library and ARM template.
(I found this: [ARM template error Bad JSON content found in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58485101/arm-template-error-bad-json-content-found-in-the-request) but it did not help me)

My Code looks like this:

```
$kvDeployResult = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name "addKeyVault" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupeName -TemplateFile ".\deploy_kv.json" -TemplateParameterFile ".\deploy_kv_param.json" -Verbose
```

Using the command like this:

```
$kvDeployResult = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name "addKeyVault" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupeName -TemplateObject $deploy_kv_hashtable -TemplateParameterObject $deploy_kv_param_hashtable -Verbose
```

results in even lesser progress and more errors.

I get this output:
[image]

My `deploy_kv.json`looks like this

```
{
"$schema":  "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion":  "1.0.0.0",
"parameters":  {
                   "name":  {
                                "type":  "string"
                            },
                   "location":  {
                                    "type":  "string"
                                },
                   "sku":  {
                               "type":  "string"
                           },
                   "accessPolicies":  {
                                          "type":  "Array"
                                      },
                   "tenant":  {
                                  "type":  "string"
                              },
                   "enabledForDeployment":  {
                                                "type":  "bool"
                                            },
                   "enabledForTemplateDeployment":  {
                                                        "type":  "bool"
                                                    },
                   "enabledForDiskEncryption":  {
                                                    "type":  "bool"
                                                },
                   "enableRbacAuthorization":  {
                                                   "type":  "bool"
                                               },
                   "enableSoftDelete":  {
                                            "type":  "bool"
                                        },
                   "softDeleteRetentionInDays":  {
                                                     "type":  "int"
                                                 },
                   "networkAcls":  {
                                       "type":  "Object"
                                   }
               },
"variables":  {

              },
"resources":  [
                  {
                      "apiVersion":  "2018-02-14",
                      "name":  "[parameters('name')]",
                      "location":  "[parameters('location')]",
                      "type":  "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
                      "properties":  {
                                         "enabledForDeployment":  "[parameters('enabledForDeployment')]",
                                         "enabledForTemplateDeployment":  "[parameters('enabledForTemplateDeployment')]",
                                         "enabledForDiskEncryption":  "[parameters('enabledForDiskEncryption')]",
                                         "enableRbacAuthorization":  "[parameters('enableRbacAuthorization')]",
                                         "accessPolicies":  "[parameters('accessPolicies')]",
                                         "tenantId":  "[parameters('tenant')]",
                                         "sku":  {
                                                     "name":  "[parameters('sku')]",
                                                     "family":  "A"
                                                 },
                                         "enableSoftDelete":  "[parameters('enableSoftDelete')]",
                                         "softDeleteRetentionInDays":  "[parameters('softDeleteRetentionInDays')]",
                                         "networkAcls":  "[parameters('networkAcls')]"
                                     },
                      "tags":  {

                               },
                      "dependsOn":  [

                                    ]
                  }
              ],
"outputs":  {

            }
```

}

---

My `deploy_kv_param.json` looks like this

```
{
"$schema":  "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion":  "1.0.0.0",
"parameters":  {
                   "name":  {
                                "value":  "vaultName"
                            },
                   "location":  {
                                    "value":  "westeurope"
                                },
                   "sku":  {
                               "value":  "Standard"
                           },
                   "accessPolicies":  {
                                          "value":  [
                                                        {
                                                            "objectId":  "objectID",
                                                            "tenantId":  "tenantId",
                                                            "permissions":  {
                                                                                "keys":  "",
                                                                                "secrets":  "Get List Set Delete Recover Backup Restore",
                                                                                "certificates":  ""
                                                                            },
                                                            "applicationId":  null
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                      },
                   "tenant":  {
                                  "value":  "tenantId"
                              },
                   "enabledForDeployment":  {
                                                "value":  false
                                            },
                   "enabledForTemplateDeployment":  {
                                                        "value":  false
                                                    },
                   "enabledForDiskEncryption":  {
                                                    "value":  false
                                                },
                   "enableRbacAuthorization":  {
                                                   "value":  false
                                               },
                   "enableSoftDelete":  {
                                            "value":  true
                                        },
                   "softDeleteRetentionInDays":  {
                                                     "value":  90
                                                 },
                   "networkAcls":  {
                                       "value":  {
                                                     "defaultAction":  "allow",
                                                     "bypass":  "AzureServices",
                                                     "ipRules":  [

                                                                 ],
                                                     "virtualNetworkRules":  [

                                                                             ]
                                                 }
                                   }
               }
```

}

---

Followup:

I tried to minimize the files to only the `$deploy_kv.json` by using defaultValues for all the properties.

It looks like this now:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "keyVaultName"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },

    "sku": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard"
    },
    "accessPolicies": {
        "type": "array",
        "defaultvalue": [
            {
                "objectId": "objId",
                "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                "permissions": {
                    "keys": "",
                    "secrets": "Get List Set Delete Recover Backup Restore",
                    "certificates": ""
                },
                "applicationId": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "tenantId": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specifies the Azure Active Directory tenant ID that should be used for authenticating requests to the key vault. Get it by using Get-AzSubscription cmdlet."
        }
    }
},
"variables": {

},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "KeyVault"
        },
        "properties": {
            "enabledForDeployment": false,
            "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false,
            "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
            "enableSoftDelete": true,
            "softDeleteRetentionInDays": 90,

            "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
            "accessPolicies": "[parameters('accessPolicies')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]",
                "family": "A"
            },
            "networkAcls": {
                "defaultAction": "Allow",
                "bypass": "AzureServices"
            }
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {

}
```

The error I get is the same. I assume the template(as the command itself states: is valid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `permissions` property to look like:

```
          "permissions": {
            "keys": [],
            "secrets": ["Get", "List", "Set", "Delete", "Recover", "Backup", "Restore"],
            "certificates": []
          },
```

Each permission property needs to be an array of strings or just an empty array.

I also had to change the `apiVersion` to:

```
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
```